# Creating an Objective-C++ Static Library in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, objective-c++

So I've developed an engine for the iPhone with which I'd like to build a couple different games.  Rather than copy and paste the files for the engine inside of each game's project directory, I'd a way to link to the engine from each game, so if I need to make a change to it I only have to do so once.  After reeding around a little bit, it seems like static libraries are the best way to do this on the iPhone.

I created a new project called Skeleton and copied all of my engine files over to it.  I used [this](http://www.amateurinmotion.com/articles/2009/02/08/creating-a-static-library-for-iphone.html) guide to create a static library, and I imported the library into a project called Chooser.  However, when I tried to compile the project, Xcode started complaining about some C++ data structures I included in a file called ControlScene.mm.  Here's my build errors:

```
  "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:


      -[ControlScene dealloc] in libSkeleton.a(ControlScene.o)


      -[ControlScene init] in libSkeleton.a(ControlScene.o)


      __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<operation_t>::deallocate(operation_t*, unsigned long)in libSkeleton.a(ControlScene.o)


      __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<operation_t*>::deallocate(operation_t**, unsigned long)in libSkeleton.a(ControlScene.o)


  "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:


      -[ControlScene init] in libSkeleton.a(ControlScene.o)


      __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<operation_t*>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)in libSkeleton.a(ControlScene.o)


      __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<operation_t>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)in libSkeleton.a(ControlScene.o)


  "std::__throw_bad_alloc()", referenced from:


      __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<operation_t*>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)in libSkeleton.a(ControlScene.o)


      __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<operation_t>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)in libSkeleton.a(ControlScene.o)


  "___cxa_rethrow", referenced from:


      std::_Deque_base<operation_t, std::allocator<operation_t> >::_M_create_nodes(operation_t**, operation_t**)in libSkeleton.a(ControlScene.o)


      std::_Deque_base<operation_t, std::allocator<operation_t> >::_M_initialize_map(unsigned long)in libSkeleton.a(ControlScene.o)


  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:


      std::_Deque_base<operation_t, std::allocator<operation_t> >::_M_create_nodes(operation_t**, operation_t**)in libSkeleton.a(ControlScene.o)


      std::_Deque_base<operation_t, std::allocator<operation_t> >::_M_initialize_map(unsigned long)in libSkeleton.a(ControlScene.o)


  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:


      ___gxx_personality_v0$non_lazy_ptr in libSkeleton.a(ControlScene.o)


      ___gxx_personality_v0$non_lazy_ptr in libSkeleton.a(MenuLayer.o)


  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:


      std::_Deque_base<operation_t, std::allocator<operation_t> >::_M_create_nodes(operation_t**, operation_t**)in libSkeleton.a(ControlScene.o)


      std::_Deque_base<operation_t, std::allocator<operation_t> >::_M_initialize_map(unsigned long)in libSkeleton.a(ControlScene.o)


ld: symbol(s) not found


collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If anybody could offer some insight as to why these problems are occuring, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that your library is dynamically linking against libstdc++. As to how to fix it, you should try "-static", "-static-libstdc++", and "-static-libgcc" in various combinations when building your library (not sure which of them are needed, but some combination thereof should make it fully static).

**Edit**
Well, it turns out that you are permitted to dynamically link against libstdc++ on the iPhone, so actually a better solution is to simply put "-lstdc++" in (that is, explicitly link against libstdc++) in your build.

Comment: @helixed, if you build the library with a Makefile or from the commandline, you can add those to your invocation of g++. If you are using Xcode, I believe there is something like "other flags" in your project build settings where you can type these in.

Comment: Yup, worked perfectly.  The setting right spot to put it is other linker flags in case anybody was wondering.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have to add this flag to the application that uses the static library, not to the library itself. Is it possible to build the library in such a way that it is not necessary to modify the build settings of the app?

Answer (score 25):

Set the "-lstdc++"  to Other Linker Flags

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by going into the build settings for Chooser, searching out "Compile Source As" and selecting Objective-C++.  This is probably a dirty solution, but it worked.

Comment: Does that mean that this effectively does the same thing as adding the -lstdc++ flag?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when trying to link a .framework. I've managed to fix it by adding an **empty** `cppstub.mm` file as source (to `Compile Sources` phase)

I guess it must be forcing some sort of C++ compilation when you do this, don't ask me why